# "select for xml auto" to get hierarchical structures for a sql table with primary key and foreign key in the same table

Tags: sql, xml

I have a table as an example:(where manager-id pointing back to the id field in the same table)

id|manager-id|name

1 |0         |John

2 |1         |Peter

Now, I am trying to work out a SQL statement, something like 'select.... for XML auto' to get the following XML as output.

```
<manager id="1" manger-id="0" name="John">
   <employee id="2" manager-id=1 name="Peter"/>
</manager>
```

much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy enough to do for one level:

```sql
SELECT
    manager.id,
    manager.[manager-id],
    manager.name,
    (
        SELECT employee.id, employee.[manager-id], employee.name
        FROM employees As employee
        WHERE employee.[manager-id] = manager.id
        FOR XML AUTO, TYPE
    )
FROM
    employees As manager
WHERE
    manager.[manager-id] = 0
FOR XML AUTO, TYPE
```

[Shape XML with Nested FOR XML Queries - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/shape-xml-with-nested-for-xml-queries?view=sql-server-ver15)

If you want deeper nesting, or more control over the output, you would probably be better to build the XML in the code which accesses the database, rather than trying to do it directly in SQL.

**NB:** Using `0` as the `manager-id` for top-level employees means you can't create a foreign key relationship, so there's nothing to prevent records from being orphaned. It would be better to use `NULL` instead, and have a proper FK in place.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I added "where manager-id>0" to the second select block. it's exactly what I want! Cheers

Comment: @cxc Sorry, I missed the `WHERE` clause on the nested query, which filters the employees based on the parent manager's ID. I've updated my answer.